# Invalid character error with flex and bison

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer, bisonc++

```
%{ 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

#ifndef TDM_PIN_MAP_TEST
#include <tdmPinMap.h>

namespace dc {
  class tdmPinMap; 
}
#endif
#undef YYLMAX
#define YYLMAX 100000
extern int lineno;
extern "C" int yywrap();
#ifndef TDM_PIN_MAP_TEST
int yyerror(dc::tdmPinMap &pm,std::string msg);
#else
int yyerror(std::string msg);
#endif
extern "C" char yytext[];
extern "C" int yylex();
%}

#ifndef TDM_PIN_MAP_TEST
%parse-param {dc::tdmPinMap &pm}
#endif

%union
{
   int val;
   char *str;
}

%token EQUALS
%token COMMA
%token SEMICOLON
%token PACKAGE
%token PIN
%token PORT
%token <str> ALPHANUMERIC
%type <str> port_name
%type <str> pin_name
%type <str> package_name

%%
             ;
pin_name         : ALPHANUMERIC
             {
               $$ = $1;
             }
             ;
%%

#ifndef TDM_PIN_MAP_TEST
int yyerror(dc::tdmPinMap &pm,std::string msg)
#else
int yyerror(std::string msg)
#endif
{
  return 1;
}
```

**My Question:**

I'm getting invalid character error with below code.

```
#ifndef TDM_PIN_MAP_TEST
%parse-param {dc::tdmPinMap &pm}
#endif
```

Here I want to define `parse-param` only if `TDM_PIN_MAP_TEST` macro is not defined, but I get below error.

```
bison -d -v -d  pinMap.ypp
pinMap.ypp:28.1: invalid character: `#'
pinMap.ypp:28.2-7: syntax error, unexpected identifier
make: *** [pinmap_yacc.cpp] Error 1
```

Line number `28` is referring to the code I have pointed out above.

Any pointer to resolve the above error is appreciated.

Comment: Basically I'm asking for conditional compilation.

Comment: Bison doesn't recognize `#ifndef` and friends, but if you want it when it *is* defined, why are you using `#ifndef`? And why do you have the `#ifndef` line twice? NB As you're using *flex(1),* `extern "C" char yytext[]` isn't correct. In *flex(1)* it is a `char *`.

Comment: @user207421 Thank you, I have updated the question, requesting you to relook.

Comment: where is the call to yyparse()

Comment: You've updated the question but you haven't answered several of mine, or fixed most of the errors I mentioned.

Comment: In some other test application where I won't passing any params to it @VenkateshNandigama

Comment: @VenkateshNandigama Somewhere else. It isn't relevant at this stage.

Comment: @user207421 1. I want it when it is not defined 2. It was typo 3. I will take that into account.

Comment: So fix your question. Again. The only way you can take everything I've said into account is by not attempting the impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bison does not provide any mechanism for conditional inclusion of directives or rules. Lines resembling C preprocessor directives (such as `#ifndef`) outside of a C code block are going to be flagged as syntax errors.

If you want to use the same bison source file for two different applicatiobs, you'll have to use some external macro preprocessor.

I'd recommend avoiding the use of `cpp` because it doesn't kniw anything about bison syntax, and will likely make many undesired changes to the bison grammar file, including expanding preprocessor directives in code blocks and unexpected macro substitutions in bison rules.

Your desired conditional inclusion looks pretty simple, so you could probably do it with a shell script. Or you could use `m4`, which must be present since bison relies on it.